# The suffix -er in English: Why is this derivational?

Tags: morphology, inflection, nouns, derivation

A typical charactersitic of inflectional suffixes is that they are productive (can occur on many words) and obligatory (are required by virtue of certain grammatical constraints). Simplistic though this may be, I was wondering about the suffix -er in English. This suffix is typically derivational insofar as it changes the category of the word bake>baker, for example. But is it not also highly productive? Fish>fisher, sleep>sleeper, mouse>mouser, eat>eater, smell>smeller, read>reader etc etc etc.

On what basis is this form truly derivational then?

Comment: In this particular case, -er is a derivational suffix. I'm unaware of a 20-21 century linguist who'd analyze it otherwise. On the other hand, if you want to become familiar with how derivation vs. inflection is treated in modern linguistic morphology, start with an excellent - and concise - summary in Bauer 2003, Chapter 6. This stuff is *always* discussed in undergrad.

Answer (score 6):

**-er** a derivational suffix because it changes the word class to which the entire expression belongs. That is what defines derivational affixes.

**bake** is a verb, but **bak-*er*** is a noun. (I assume the stem **bak** because the final letter *e* is not pronounced.)

Productivity is not a sufficient criterion for the distinction of inflection and derivation.

English uses zero-conversion, i.e. the possibility that one expression belongs to more than one word class, e.g. *The dog wants to **run***, and *a **run***. That means that one must take care when looking at the verb/noun distinction in English.

Comment: So the distinction between inflection and derivation requires references to productive, obligatoriness, and word-class changing properties. Are all of these necessary and sufficient conditions?

Comment: @mateuz Globally, yes. There's room to quibble, though. At least _productive_ is a scalable notion. The question is then from which point onwards we want to view an affix as productive. I'm not sure about _obligatory_: in what way is **-er** obligatory?

Comment: I am working under the assumption that INFLECTIONAL suffixes are typically "productive" (insofar as they can occur on a broad swath of words) and "obligatory (insofar as they are required for grammaticality). Thus, at least in EN, verbal tense is inflectional. However, -er is derivational insofar as it derives another category from the root. It concerns me though that it is also "productive".

Comment: I'd appreciate any input you may have on distinguishing inflectional suffixes from derivational ones, from a typological perspective!

Comment: @mateuz re productivity. I don't think I'd employ this notion concerning the distinction inflection/derivation. Often closed word classes have paradigms different from open classes, but does that mean that affixes for closed word classes are less productive? If you insist on using the notion I'd suggest the opposite approach: an affix may not be unique.

Comment: @mateuz re typology. The standard approach is always to view inflectional suffixes as **following** derivational suffixes. It's _bak-er-s_, but not _bak-s-er_, etc. However, the distinction between inflection and derivation remains artificial if it doesn't head gradience. Clearly, derivational affixes can grammaticalize into inflectional ones, and that means that there must be a greyzone. It's not a black/white issue.

Comment: The really important thing [about inflections](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) is that they're ***Paradigmatic***. That is, they form paradigms, although in [agglutinative languages](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Turkish.html) the paradigms tend to be one-dimensional; nevertheless, they are paradigms, and that's what defines inflection. That's also why English has so little inflection; there are almost no productive paradigms left in English. Plenty of [non-productive ones, like this](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.html), though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- good point. But no one would argue that the PLURAL (in e.g. Indoeuropean languages) is anything but inflectional even though it isn't part of a paradigm ... or is it?

Comment: In English, _I am/we are, you are/you are, he is/they are, she is/they are, it is/they are_ is an inflectional paradigm. It's not as obvious as _amo/amamus, amas/amatis, amat/amant_, but then Latin is heavily inflected and English is almost uninflected.

Comment: @mateuz, why do you think the plural isn't part of a paradigm?

Comment: @Thomas *"**-er** a derivational suffix because it changes the word class to which the entire expression belongs. That is what defines derivational affixes."* How about diminutive suffixes? And how about causative verbal suffixes, like *fugĕre, fugare*? And how about various suffixes that turn adjectives into other adjectives, such as *red, reddish* and *red, reddest*, and a host of other examples and categories? From Wikipedia: *"However, derivational affixes do not necessarily alter the lexical category; they may merely change the meaning of the base, while leaving the category unchanged."*

Comment: @Cerberus Please post that as a question.

Comment: @Cerberus one approach is to consider those affixes to be changing the part of speech subcategory, e.g. intransitive->causative. But it's certainly the case that derivational-inflectional is more of a continuum than a truly categorial distinction

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: Right, but then there are things like *puer → puerulus → puellus → puella → puellula,* and *quinque → quintus → quintilis → quintilianus* ... my position is that even changing of a subclass of parts of speech is not the "essential" criterion that defines derivation versus inflexion; I tend more towards Lawler's "derivation is very general, inflexion is a subclass that's about paradigms". Or something.

Comment: @Cerberus I think that view amounts to the same thing. If inflection is paradigmatic, derivation is syntagmatic, which it's pretty much the same as saying it's about part of speech (sub)categories.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: We all agree -(i)lis and -(a)nus in Latin are both suffixes, don't we? Does a very small (if not absent) change in meaning necessarily entail a syntagmatic change? You can still do exactly the same things with the word syntactically, as in put it before a noun, give it certain arguments, etc. How do you determine what constitutes a subcategory of a part of speech, and why does a different number/person/mode/voice/etc. not constitute a change in subcategory, except just because of traditional terminology? (I tend to agree with your statement that it is a continuum more.)

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about exotic languages such as Latin, so I can't comment on your examples. But I think we largely agree; my point was that contrasting inflection and derivation by saying that inflection is paradigmatic is much the same as saying that derivation changes part of speech (sub)category (i.e. its syntagmatic). How that is operationalised is a different matter.

Answer (score 3):

I am not convinced that either one of these answers in correct. Most Indo-European languages have suffixes that make verbs into participles (i.e. adjectives), like English go > going, Latin amo > amans, Greek legō > legōn. All grammars describe these as inflectional elements. They are not listed separately in dictionaries. I have the feeling that the distinction between “inflections” and “derivational suffixes” is largely artificial.

Comment: But what isn't a convention in linguistics? Even concepts like noun and verb are arguably conventions. Anyway, I see your point. Perhaps there's no real distinction between inflection and derivation... (though as the examples you gave are part of paradigms, apply productively, they clearly have inflectional aspects, no? perhaps they are just LESS inflectional than others)

Comment: Derived forms are normally not listed in dictionaries if they are predictable. Eg in Australian languages, wherein causative is often a highly productive and predictable process, derived causative verbs will often not be listed in dictionaries unless there is something idiosyncratic (i.e. unpredictable) about them.

Comment: While participles behave similarly to adjectives, they are not generally considered to be the same part of speech in linguistics. From what I remember, in traditional Latin grammar participles were a word class of their own, and in modern grammatical analyses of English participles are considered to be verbs. Relevant question about a similar topic: [Is the {-ing} of the gerund a verbal inflectional suffix?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17175)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you've said the correct distinguishing factors between derivational and inflectional affixes.

The primary factor I think is that derivational affixes often change the part of speech of a lexical item, and inflectional affixes don't. What this means is that the concept of the lexical item changes substantially. There is a huge difference between the concept of *running*, a physical action, and the concept of *a runner*, a person who regularly runs because of it being their habit or job. These conceptual differences mean that derived words are often listed separately in dictionaries. Additionally, semantic change will affect the related parts of speech separately. Consider the difference between *a lecture*, *to lecture* and *a lecturer*. *To lecture* has changed it's meaning so that it now almost always means to tell someone off with a long speech. *A lecturer* retains the original meaning of someone who teaches through speeches. *A lecture* has both meanings. But note that not all derivational affixes do change the part of speech: the suffix *-ship* turns the noun *friend* into another noun, *friendship*.

Inflectional affixes generally don't communicate real-world or dictionary information. They instead communicate semantic categories. There's no hard and fast rule about whether something will be a semantic category or not, but we all know the really common ones: plurality, tense, agreement markers etc. No English dictionary would have separate entries for *dog* and *dogs* because the concepts are too similar, which is a good indicator that the plural marker is inflectional. No English dictionary will have separate entries for *jumped* and *jumping*, so those tense/aspect markers are inflectional.

Sometimes it's a little bit hard to decide whether an affix is derivational or inflectional. Which one is *dis-* in *disclose*?

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you. One quick follow-up. You wrote "The primary factor I think is that derivational affixes often change the part of speech of a lexical item, and inflectional affixes don't" -- but perhaps it is more accurate to simplify this, "... often significantly change the meaning of the word to which they attach", e.g. bake>baker>bakery. This way, both -r and -ery can be considered as derivational rather than inflectional. What do you think?

Comment: Yes that's a good thought.

Comment: So, a good way to determine if a suffix is inflectional, is with reference to: (1) Can it attach to many words? (2) Is it grammatically necessary? (3) Does it have little/no semantic effect on the meaning of the word to which it attaches? [this last one seems hard to elaborate -- what do you say?]

Comment: No I don't think any of those are necessarily accurate, but it's hard to come up with a single universally acceptable definition. It may be that there isn't a binary difference but more of a spectrum with prototypical derivational and inflectional affixes at each end.