# Is -ing a derivational suffix in leading?

Tags: morphology

If leading is used as an adjective here,is -ing a derivational suffix or is it only an inflectional suffix?

Comment: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17175/is-the-ing-of-the-gerund-a-verbal-inflectional-suffix

Comment: (1) Where is "here"? (2) What sentence is _leading_ used in? (3) What will it tell you if you find out whether it's derivational or inflectional?